# How to extract a field parameter from optional, or throw exception if null?

Tags: java, java-8

```
String result = service.getResult();

if (result == null) {
    DaoObject obj = crudRepository.findOne(..);
    if (obj != null) {
        result = obj.getContent();
    } else {
        throw NotFoundException();
    }
}

service.process(result);
```

If `DaoObject` would be an `Optional<DaoObject>`, what could I do to achieve the same as above using java 8?

Something with `.orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException());`, but how would the above code look exactly with streams?

Sidequestion: should I use `() -> new NotFoundException()` or `NotFoundException::new`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. 
This would result in the following code:

```
Optional<DaoObject> obj = crudRepository.findOne(..);

result = obj.orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException()).getContent();
```

Or if you prefer you can split the statement to make it more readable:

```
DoaObject object = obj.orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException());
result = object.getContent();
```

Note that `() -> new NotFoundException()` and `NotFoundException::new` are exactly the same, so it is just a matter of what you think is more readable.

Comment: That's a very clean solution! Just a short follow up question: if my exception is to be created with a `String` message like `new NotFoundException("test")`, then I could not use the `::new` syntax, right?

Comment: You should then use the `() -> new NotFoundException("test");`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
Optional<DaoObject> obj = crudRepository.findOne(..);
result = obj.orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new).getContent();
```

> Sidequestion: should I use `() -> new NotFoundException()` or `NotFoundException::new`?

That's just a matter of choice. Both expressions will do the same.